# Stream API - how to return map of unique task name - average result?

Tags: java, java-stream, average

I have a `CourseResult` class

```java
public class CourseResult {
    private final Person person;
    private final Map<String, Integer> taskResults; // Here names and results of tasks are saved 

    public CourseResult(final Person person, final Map<String, Integer> taskResults) {
        this.person = person;
        this.taskResults = taskResults;
    }

    public Person getPerson() {
        return person;
    }

    public Map<String, Integer> getTaskResults() {
        return taskResults;
    }
}
```

Here is my method signature

```
public Map<String, Double> averageScoresPerTask(Stream<CourseResult> programmingResults) {
```

I need to return an average result of every task.

Comment: Are you sure your intention to accept a stream of course results (for 0..n persons) and to return a single result (for 1 person) is correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd `flatMap` that stream to a stream of the `taskResults`' entries, and then use `Collectors.averagingDouble` to get the average per task:

```java
public Map<String, Double> averageScoresPerTask(Stream<CourseResult> programmingResults) {
    return programmingResults
            .flatMap(c -> c.getTaskResults().entrySet().stream())
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                        Map.Entry::getKey,
                        Collectors.averagingDouble(Map.Entry::getValue)));
}
```

Comment: `.flatMap( ... )` <==> `.map(CourseResult::getTaskResults) .map(Map::entrySet) .flatMap(Set::stream)`